# Wrong positioned Ampere-meter and Voltmeter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

I'm dealing with a problem here and even that I'm trying to solve it i can't

It says:

> *In what figures the voltmeter and ampere-meter are wrong positioned?*

[image]

I think that all the the others are correct except the second one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This belongs on EE.SE (now why wasn't that obvious in the first place!?).

Answer (score 1):

You can't talk about "correct" without a definition of what you are trying to achieve.  However, you can rule out some obviously bad arrangements if the placement of the meters keeps the circuit from working, even though we have to guess at what the intended "working" is.  This is a poorly specified problem, or there is context surrounding it that you haven't given us.

Ideal meters measure what they are supposed to measure but otherwise don't effect the thing they are measuring.  The ideal voltmeter therefore has infinite resistance (looks like a open circuit), and the ideal ammeter 0 resistance (looks like a short circuit).  Start by removing the voltmeter and replace the ammeter with a short and see if the circuit would still operate as it is (presumably) supposed to.

From this we see that circuits 1, 3, and 4 would still work, but circuit 2 has a dead short accross its battery and the voltmeter blocking any current to the load.  This means circuit 2 is wrong, as you already pointed out.

In the remaining circuits, the batttery and load aren't effected by the meters, but that doesn't mean the meters are showing you anything useful.

In circuit 1 the ammeter is showing the total battery (and load) current, but the voltmeter is only showing the voltage accross one of the two loads.  Is that right?  We can't tell from your description because we don't know what the intent of the voltmeter is.  If the point was to see the voltage accross the second load, then this is correct.

Circuit 3 is the same thing.  The ammeter will show the current going thru all three elements and the voltmeter the voltage accross the top load.  If that's what was intended, then this is correct.

Circuit 4 is almost certainly "correct" since there is only one voltage to measure and one current to measure, and the meters are hooked up to measure them.

Comment: In figure 4, while it will "work", all the voltmeter will tell you is the battery voltage, which doesn't seem all that useful (you should know the battery voltage). It _should_ be roughly equivalent to the voltage drop across the device, but seems redundant.

Comment: @Phil: You don't know what kind of load it is or anything about the battery.  There are certainly cases where watching the battery voltage and current can be very useful in diagnosing a system or verying it is working correctly.  Often the point is that you *don't* know the battery voltage.  Batteries are not constant voltage sources.  In fact, battery voltage as a function of temperature, time, state of charge, and current drain can be quite complicated.  Battery monitoring and management can be complicated and non-trivial sub-systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite opposite. All are correct except the second one. Ampere-meter should be positioned in series configuration and voltmeter should be positioned in parallel configuration to the measured element. Notice that voltmeters should have very high resistance, so that most of the current will flow through the measured element. The bigger resistance of the voltmeter, the better it's accuracy. Similarly, ampere-meters should have as low resistance as possible, to limit the influence on the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The ammeter actually creates a short across the battery in the second figure (so that one is certainly wrong).   Very likely, this would cause damage to the ammeter, or at least result in a blown input protection fuse.

I think the other diagrams are OK, depending on what it is you are trying to measure (which is open to interpretation).

This answer assumes that the components marked as an X within a circle is an unknown component, and not a "mixer", which is what this symbol actually stands for, and which is almost never probed using either an ammeter or a voltmeter, because such a measurement would tell you almost nothing of interest.